Debugging 2D elastic collision code in Julia
I'm trying to write what should be, in principle, a relatively straight forward project: a program that deals with elastic collisions between particles in 2D, that then creates a movie of the scene using Plots.jl. I've pretty much added everything I thought was necessary to be able to work the case of a monoatomic gas (I'm trying to simulate some thermodynamic properties for a class); I know the collision check with the walls and the ensuing particle bounce work properly, and same goes for the particle overlap (dist_between_centers <= r1+r2) that should trigger the elastic collision between them... but, for some reason, the updated velocities don't work as intended, all despite my checking and re-checking that I'm using the correct expressions for said velocity update.
I've added everything a larger, more general program ought to have, with a list that takes in structs and handles collisions. Everything that (imo) should mean it works in principle, meaning a bunch of functions that are declared aren't even being used (including a list to check for all possible 1-to-1 collision pairs). But what's the point if even the most basic case of 2 particles colliding doesn't even work?
Here is where Im getting the expression for the velocity update - Wikipedia link: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Elastic_collision
At this point, this problem should be solved, but it isn't. Because I'm assuming there must be a small (but very silly) error that I can't, for the life of me, find. I even asked ChatGPT just to see what it had to offer so I wouldn't bother folks with this but, as expected, came back with useless garble. So, here I am, and here's the full code for ppl to see, maybe have a chuckle at my expense, but, really, any help with debugging (I know, it's silly) would be much appreciated:
using LinearAlgebra
using OhMyREPL
using Plots

mutable struct particle
    pos :: Vector{Float64}  #-position
    v   :: Vector{Float64}  #-velocity

    m   :: Float64          #-mass
    r   :: Float64          #-radius
    id  :: Int64            #-the ID of the particle
end
#--the following function takes a number that represents the number of elements in a list.
#--the assumption is that all elements of the list interact with one another.
#--it then gives back a list of all enumerated pair-wise interactions by ID, without repetition,in the form of an array of arrays.
function getInteractionIds(N)
    interactionIds = []
    i = 1;j = 1
    while i<=N
        j = i
        while j<=N
            if j != i push!(interactionIds,  [i,j] ) end
            j +=1
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return interactionIds
end
#-a random number within a range.
function randRange(A,B)
    return A + (B-A)*rand()
end
#-building a list of ALL the data from a list of structs.
function getData(list)
    #NOTE: not the most efficient way of doing this. I could well have done this from the beginning, but I want it to be readable.
    #particle: pos.x pos.y v.x v.y r
    data = zeros(length(list), 6)
    for i=1:length(list)
        data[i,1] = list[i].pos[1]  #-pos.x
        data[i,2] = list[i].pos[2]  #-pos.y
        data[i,3] = list[i].v[1]    #-v.x
        data[i,4] = list[i].v[2]    #-v.y
        #-lone scalar magnitudes that are not components.
        data[i,5] = list[i].r       #-v.r
        data[i,6] = norm(list[i].v) #-the MAGNITUDE of all velocities.
    end
    return data
end
#-drawing a 10x10 box (arbitrary units)
function drawData(data)#-this is still making a TON of assumptions in terms of box size, marker unit size, aspect ratio, etc.
    scatter(data[1:end,1],data[1:end,2],
            xlims = [0,10],ylims = [0,10],
            color="red",
            markersize = data[1,5]*marker_unit,
            aspect_ratio = 1,
            dpi=80)
end
#---------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------
function wallChecks(list)
    collision_counter = 0#-a counter for how many times a particle collides with the wall.
    for element in list
        if element.pos[1]>10.0 || element.pos[1]< 0.0
            element.v[1] *= -1#-perfect reflection in x.
            collision_counter += 1
        end
        if element.pos[2]>10.0 || element.pos[2]< 0.0
            element.v[2] *= -1#-perfect reflection in y.
            collision_counter += 1
        end
    end
end
function Euler(p)#-Euler integration
    p.pos = p.pos + p.v*Δt#-a tad crappy but whatever. It works for our purposes.
end
function step(list)#-applies Euler integration to ALL elements in the list.
    for element in list
        Euler(element)
    end
end
#---------------------------------------------

#-declaration of the walls of the system goes here.
Δt = 0.4
N_particles = 2
#list = [particle([randRange(2.5,7.5),randRange(2.5,7.5)], randn(2),   1.0,1.0,id) for id=1:N_particles]
p1 = particle([2.5,5],[+0.0,0.0], 1.0,1.0, 1)
p2 = particle([7.5,5],[-0.2,0.0], 1.0,1.0, 2)
list = [p1,p2]

marker_unit = 40
#using the macro  @animate:
T_UNITS = 1200
IPs = getInteractionIds(N_particles)#-list of all INTERACTION PAIRS.

# #-starting our simulation with the intent of animating it:
anim = @animate for T=1:T_UNITS
     #time = round(Δt*T, digits=2)
     wallChecks(list)         #--actual enforcement of boundary conditions that returns data from the collision checks.
    #-----------------------------
    conditionA = (p1.pos-p2.pos)·(p1.pos-p2.pos)
    conditionB = (p1.r+p2.r)^2
    if conditionA <= conditionB
        #println("----------------------COLLIDING.")
      p1.v = p1.v - ( 2*p2.m/( p1.m+p2.m ) ) * ( dot(p1.v - p2.v , p1.pos - p2.pos) / dot(p1.pos - p2.pos , p1.pos - p2.pos) ) * (p1.pos - p2.pos)
      p2.v = p2.v - ( 2*p1.m/( p1.m+p2.m ) ) * ( dot(p2.v - p1.v , p2.pos - p1.pos) / dot(p2.pos - p1.pos , p2.pos - p1.pos) ) * (p2.pos - p1.pos)
    else
        #println("----------------------NOT COLLIDING.")
    end

#-----------------------------
    listData  = getData(list)      #--collecting the data of our particles per current time step for later processing...
    box  = drawData(listData)       #--the drawing part using a very limited, unwieldy function.
#-----------------------------
    Euler(p1)
    Euler(p2)
     #step(list)
end every 4
gif(anim, "animaM.mp4")


println("FINISHED.")


